# How to measure the content of sugar, proteins and fat in meat?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, food-chemistry

I do a research project for Science Symposium and I need to measure a content of proteins, sugar and fat in a meat. Unfortunately, I have found only the methods that require specials apparatus/device that I do not have in my school. I'm a student of secondary school, so I need a simple method. Could you please recommend me one?

Comment: Extract with toluene (fat), then extract with water (sugar), dry the rest? The water fraction will also contain sodium & potassium salts.